# Select by Location on Virtual layer works but not on MS SQL Server layer

Tags: qgis, virtual-layer

I have point data within an MS SQL Server.

I can add it as a layer to QGIS by creating a DB connection under MS SQL Server and double clicking the table listed.

I also have a polygon layer again added via same MS SQL Server connection.

If I try and do Select by Location (or Select Within plugin) - asking for all points that are within the polygons - the result is that all points are selected not just the ones within the polygons:

[image: ![enter image description here]

But if I add the points layer as a Virtual layer (using same connection) the Select by Location works - only points within polygons selected:
[image: ![enter image description here]

Why? Surely it should work with the direct SQL connection method? What is the difference between virtual and direct SQL layer?

Comment: Maybe the CRS is properly set in the virtual layer but not in the original layer?

Comment: Yes, I have had that before but no the cause in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I realised that other linked tables were ok with select by location.

Checked the underlying query in the DB and that was the problem - didn't have a proper unique ID attached.

Changed the query to include unique [id] as first field:
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [URN]) AS [id]

That made the difference.